# How to fit c# application to monitor with different resolution?

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-resolution

I usually work with two monitors and two differents resolutions. 1366x768 and 1920x1080.
My prob is that my WPF application doesn't fit the monitor with biggest resolution when it runs on monitor 1366x768.
I found differents solutions but none of them work for me.
My last attempt is :

```
   Screen actualScreen = Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(App.Current.MainWindow).Handle);
   App.Current.MainWindow.Height = actualScreen.Bounds.Height;
   App.Current.MainWindow.Width = actualScreen.Bounds.Width;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to layout your screen using a fixed resolution size, use other properties of the GUI controls to:

1. Dock along side another control (beside, above, or below).
2. Add minimum padding between the control and the control it docks next to.
3. Set a minimum size for the control. That can force scroll bars on the Application window if the user resizes it too small or the monitor's resolution is not large enough to fit your applications layout.

Those are some of the "responsive design" properties of a control in WPF.

My advice when laying out a `Panel`: start with placing the primary control and then fit the other controls on that `Panel` in relation to that primary `Control` (using the Alignment/Margin properties).